# unable to load configuration from uwsgi when attempting to run flask app via uwsg

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I've the following uwsgi app.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
callable = app
socket = :5000
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

wsgi.py content:

```
from app import start

start()
```

and finally app.py which is the Flask app itself (pretty long so I'll only put the relevant):

```
# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


... all sort of methods here ...


def start():
    print("STARTING !!!")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

all files are in the same folder.
when I'm running `uwsgi app.ini` I'm getting this:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
unable to load configuration from uwsgi
```

why is this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look shows two problems. First, `uwsgi` and `app.run()` aren't compatible. You use the latter when you're using the Flask development environment. `uwsgi` wants the object that holds the Flask instance. By convention, that's `app`, though you can use a different name (and configure `uwsgi` to look for a different name).

And that's the second issue. `uwsgi` has loaded `wsgi.py` (causing the `app.run()` that's getting you the most of what you're seeing. Then it's looking for `app`. But because you're importing from `app`, the `app` that `wsgi.py` has isn't the Flask instance.

The simple thing to do would be (in uwsgi.ini) to replace

```
file=wsgi.py
```

with

```
module=app:app
```

That should bypass the call to `start()`, letting `uwsgi` handle things.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I've replaced those lines you were referring to in app.ini.
I guess it means that wsgi.py file isn't relevant anymore.
The problem is that still I've some init code I should run in the Flask app, where should I put it in such case?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/ is a common approach to that need